# @Valid does not work for nested object in bean class in spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-validator, javax.validation

I have a Bean class which has one nested object like below.

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import javax.validation.Valid;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    public class UserRequestDTO {

        private String transactionId;

        private String email;

        @Valid @NotNull HistoryRequestDTO historyRequestDTO;
    }
```

This is the nested object bean class.

```
import javax.validation.constraints.*;
    @Data
    public class HistoryRequestDTO {

        @NotNull(message = Constants.INVALID_FIELD_DATA_EN_US)
        @Range(min = 0, max = 100, message = Constants.INVALID_FIELD_DATA_EN_US)
        @NumberFormat(style = NumberFormat.Style.NUMBER)
        Integer pageNumber;

        @NotNull(message = Constants.INVALID_FIELD_DATA_EN_US)
        @Range(min = 50, max = 500, message = Constants.INVALID_FIELD_DATA_EN_US)
        @NumberFormat(style = NumberFormat.Style.NUMBER)
        Integer pageSize;
    }
```

I already have implemented validator for HistoryRequestDTO and working fine seperately. But when I use UserRequestDTO, HistoryRequestDTO validator does not work.

I tried to implement seperate validator for UserRequestDTO, but still  it is not calling  HistoryRequestDTO validator.

Comment: Do you get any errors or so? Do you have java bean standards followed? Please add the imports as well

Comment: I have added imports in question. I am not getting any error as such, just that it is not calling nested object validator. because of this I am able to send wrong data in request.

Answer (score 2):

> try this
>
> @Valid usage show here  for nested object in bean class just check
>   once..

[hibernate validator](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.1/reference/en-US/html/validator-usingvalidator.html#d0e410)

Comment: I am doing same but its not working. its not calling nested class validator to prform validation.